# How to understand Bean in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am a beginner of Spring and I still can't understand clearly what Bean is. From its definition, it seems a object that is determined by some pre-set configuration files or using annotation on a class. Once the spring starts up, the bean has been created. But can Spring use DI to create some instances of which attributes are not pre-determined?(Like, a user posts a json from website to Spring. And this json contains some data that are used to new a instance. Can Spring use this json to create the instance by using DI?)

Comment: That's not something the IoC container will do. Spring MVC's `HttpMessageConverter` instances will do that. The instances deserialized out of the JSON are not Spring beans.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bean is just the object created by your spring application. As you know any spring application has several interacting objects working together to give rise to the desired programmed behavior.

A Bean is basically a managed object i.e at run time the IOC container creates the bean object based on its definition supplied by the coder or as configured in the apllicationContext.xml file under beans tag, and injects it to other classes as required.

Any Spring application is basically a conglomeration of various objects interacting with each other, these objects or beans collaborate to create the application.

A Bean's lifecycle is managed by the Spring IOC container.

The JSON consumed by the Spring Application is taken care of by the HttpMessageConverter. When recieving a new request, the Spring framework will use the ***content-type*** header to determine the media type of the request.
It will then try to find the corresponding converter, available in the classpath of the application, to convert the Request body.

Thus its clear that the incoming request body object is not managed by the Spring IOC container and hence is not a Bean.

But these deserialized instances are used as Data Transfer Objects in a Spring application's various layers like, service, DAO, controller.

Comment: So it sounds like a bean should be some kind of fixed infrastructure in a application(i.e the connection object when using jdbc) and not a temporary object?

Comment: All those objects in an application are reffered to as Beans which are completely managed by the Spring IOC container. A bean is an object that is instantiated, assembled, and otherwise managed by a Spring IoC container, not by HttpMessageConverter. See https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html

Comment: Thank you John. I think I might understand what you mean. But I still have one more question. It maybe a little silly. The question is how to determine which object should be coded as bean when developing a web app based on Spring. Are there any principles?

Comment: It's not silly, it's relevant. It depends on the problem at hand, and basically all the objects at controller layer, service layer and DAO layer can be configured as bean.

Comment: I got it. Thanks again~

Answer (score 1):

Spring beans are the objects that comprise your application and are managed by the Spring framework. Comparing them to the concepts of JavaBeans and POJOs provides some explanatory [context](http://www.shaunabram.com/beans-vs-pojos/), and the Spring [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/) contains extensive documentation of Spring beans, including this summary:

> A bean definition essentially is a recipe for creating one or more
>   objects. The container looks at the recipe for a named bean when
>   asked, and uses the configuration metadata encapsulated by that bean
>   definition to create (or acquire) an actual object.

Also included in the reference documentation are descriptions of various ways to instantiate beans via an [xml-based](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-definition) or [annotation-based](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-annotation-config) configuration approach as well as the [Java Config](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java) approach (which also uses annotations). This is managed by the Spring BeanFactory interface (API [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html); source [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.java)).

> The @Bean annotation is used to indicate that a method instantiates,
>   configures and initializes a new object to be managed by the Spring
>   IoC container. For those familiar with Spring’s  XML
>   configuration the @Bean annotation plays the same role as the 
>   element. You can use @Bean annotated methods with any Spring
>   @Component, however, they are most often used with @Configuration
>   beans.

You refer in the question to Dependency Injection (DI), a design pattern based on the Inversion of Control principle, which is a critical part of the Spring Framework, particularly for bean instantiation. DI allows values to be passed into the object from outside. The Spring documentation describes both the [constructor-based](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-constructor-injection) and [setter-based](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-setter-injection) approaches to DI provided by the Spring IoC container for instantiating objects (beans).