# Multiple objects are being for singleton bean used to serialize @RequestBody

Tags: java, spring

I have a following spring managed bean.

```
@Entity
@Component
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer","handler"})
public class Offer {
     // fields and getter, setters toString hashtag
}
```

And following endpoint.

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<Offer> publishOffer(@RequestBody Offer offer) throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println (Thread.currentThread ().getName ());
    System.out.println ("Before thread sleep => " + offer);
    Thread.currentThread ().sleep (90000);
    System.out.println ("After thread sleep => " + offer + "from thread " + Thread.currentThread ().getName ());
    return null;
}
```

`@RequestBody` Model i.e. `Offer` is Singleton. I have added `Sleep(90000)` intentionally. I made 3 requests within 90 sec of spam.

As Offer bean is a singleton bean there should be only one object of it in `spring` container.

Why am I getting 3 different objects of `Offer` bean?

```
After thread sleep => Offer{jobTitle='Manager'}from thread http-nio-8080-exec-1
After thread sleep => Offer{jobTitle='Sr. Software 1'}from thread http-nio-8080-exec-2
After thread sleep => Offer{jobTitle='Sr. Software 4'}from thread http-nio-8080-exec-3
```

Comment: Why is it a Singleton ?  
Also, the offer object is retrieved from the request body, so the values will depend of the recevied request.

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel I am just playing with the code, no business case here

Comment: I mean, you state that it's a singleton but I don't see why. The object is simply deserialized from the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Object might be managed by spring based on your annotations, but the requestBody coming in is not a spring managed bean. Look at the answer by @john Doe . It is very well explained
[How to understand Bean in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44475523/how-to-understand-bean-in-spring)
To validate this, try to retrieve the bean from the IOC container and print it, it should be singleton